# Unexpected behaviour when re-ordering facets (for ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like some help understanding an error so that it can't happen again.

I was producing some (gg) plots and wanted to change the order of facets for aesthetic reasons. The way I did this had unexpected consequences and almost slipped through the net when I was checking the results - it could have caused serious problems with the article I'm working on!

I wanted to re-order the facets based on a numerical vector that I could define up-front
E.g. facet_order=c(1,2,4,3). This was so the graph syntax could be copied / pasted for repeat graphs more easily and I wouldn't have to dig around too much in the code each time.

```
# some example data:
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4), y=c(1,2,3,4), facet_var=factor(c('A','B','C','D')))

# First plot (facet order defined by default):
ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~facet_var, nrow = 1)+labs(title='Original data')
```

In the second plot, facets 'C' and 'D' are swapped as intended:

```
# reorder facets (normal method)
df$facet_var2 <- factor(df$facet_var, levels=c('A','B','D','C')) # Set the facets var 
as a factor, to define the order

# Second plot:
ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~facet_var2, nrow = 1)+labs(title='Re- 
ordered facets', subtitle='working as expected')
```

However, this is the mistake I made:

```
# different syntax to reorder the facets
df$facet_var3 <- df$facet_var # duplicate the faceting variable
levels(df$facet_var3) <- levels(df$facet_var3)[c(1,2,4,3)]  # I thought I was just 
re-ordering the levels here

# Third plot:
ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~facet_var3, nrow = 1)+labs(title='Re- 
ordered facets (method 2)',subtitle='Unexpected behaviour')
```

In the third graph, it looks like the data doesn't move, but the facet labels do, which is obviously wrong.

Digging a bit deeper, it appears that my syntax changed not only the order of the factor, but actually the underlying data *in* the factor variable. Is this behaviour expected?

Here's the crux of it:

```
facet_order <- c(1,2,4,3)

levels(df$facet_var) <- levels(df$facet_var)[facet_order]  # bad
df$facet_var <- factor(df$facet_var, levels=c(levels(df$facet_var)[facet_order)) # 
good
```

Obviously I now know the solution but I'm still unclear what I actually did wrong here. Any pointers?

Hang on while I try and fix the images:

[image: a busy cat]

[image: a busy cat]

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Images: [image.png](https://postimg.cc/XGqJNvN9)
![a](https://i.postimg.cc/1RGKCXGQ/image.png)
![b](https://i.postimg.cc/W36JnDQY/image.png)
![c](https://i.postimg.cc/qvSnMHsw/image.png)

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behavior.  In the 'unexpected' attempt you are not re-ordering the levels, you are overwriting them.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento yes I get that that's what's happening but I don't understand why. When you type levels(some_df$some_factor) the output is the factor order - which is what I want to rewrite. I don't understand why editing the levels would affect the underlying data?

Comment: Well instead of trying to replace the same values in a different order, try completely different values and then see if you understand.  `levels(df$facet_var3) <- c("blue", "red", "orange", "purple"); df$facet_var3`.  You are changing the labels of the levels.  Compare also `factor(df$facet_var, labels = c('A','B','D','C'))` and `factor(df$facet_var, levels = c('A','B','D','C'))`.

Answer (score 2):

quick'n'dirty: posterior reordering with `fct_reorder` of `{forcats}` (part of tidyverse):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ fct_reorder(facet_var, c('B','A','D','C')),
               nrow = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful tip, although in my case I wanted to avoid re-typing the factor order since they are long and complex strings (and of course a single mis-typed letter would mean the whole plot would fail - with a typically opaque error message!).